# Android.mk: Build library for Linux

Tags: c++, linux, android-ndk

I have an Android.mk file for building native library for Android. Can I use this file and build library for Linux (both of 32 and 64 version)?

Comment: Which settings do you want to reuse for Linux build? Probably, the CFLAGS and library dependencies will be different.

Answer (score 2):

In simple cases you can use command line (it assumes that native gcc is installed conventionally on your Linux machine):

```
ndk-build APP_ABI=x86 TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX= PRIVATE_SYSROOT_LINK= APP_LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib \
  libs/x86/libMY_NATIVE_NAME.so
```