# Using AndroidStudio + gradle + NDK to build Library for Android and Linux

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, portability

**I want to build a shared library with different variants / versions that I can use on Android and in Linux applications.**

Therefor, I set up an Android Project consisting of an app module and a (native C/C++) library module as outlined in the official [Android Studio documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#create-sources)<sup>*</sup>, so that my complete build tool chain for the library consists of<sup>**</sup>:

- Android Studio
- gradle / `build.gradle`
- cmake / `CMakeLists.txt`
- ninja
- clang

My code is actually portable, e.g. I used `#ifdef __ANDROID__` around Android specific code paths, and I can compile a working Linux shared object *by hand*, that is, by invoking the compiler from the command line.

**Is there a nice way to use the above tool chain to create both the `.so` files for Android and Linux, without maintaining two redundant sets of build configuration files?**

<sub>** I followed the documentation from May 2017, which is almost identical to this [archive.org snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20170222083606/https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html) from February 2017.*</sub>

<sub>*** I do not use Android.mk and ndk-build, so that [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24426059/android-mk-build-library-for-linux) does not apply for me, even though the purpose is the same.*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, it's easier than I thought. In this case, Gradle is not needed for the Linux version, and the Cmake configuration is mostly portable across Android and Linux. So theoretically, you can just:

```
cd $AndroidProject/librarymodule/build
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" .. && make
```

As said before, this circumvents gradle, meaning that the configurations in the `build.gradle` are nerver applied.

The easiest fix is to add those settings to `CMakeLists.txt` like this:

```
# (...) Common defintions for both platforms here (...)

if (ANDROID)
    find_library( log-lib log )
    target_link_libraries( librarymodule ${log-lib} )
else ( )
    find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
    target_compile_definitions ( librarymodule PUBLIC ENABLE_DEBUG_LOGGING linux HAVE_LIBUDEV)
    target_include_directories ( librarymodule PRIVATE  src/main/cpp ../otherlib/src/main/cpp )
    target_compile_options ( librarymodule PRIVATE -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -O0 -g -std=c++11 -fexceptions )
    target_link_libraries( librarymodule pthread ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
)
```

Theres a disadvantage in having identical / similar settings scattered across `build.grade` for Android and `CMakeLists.txt` for Linux. Possible solutions:

- Move all those settings into `CMakeLists.txt`. Should be trivial.
- Try to use Gradle as a wrapper for both Android and Linux and move all settings to `build.gradle`. Could be complex.

Comment: If you want to run native cmake from Android Studio, I suggest that you simply add `task nativeBuild(type: Exec) {
    commandLine "/usr/local/bin/cmake", <parameters>...;
    gradle.buildFinished {
        nativeBuild.execute()
    }
}
` to your **build.gradle**.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for a similar solution, but I think there is currently no way to do it. There is no Android-Studio plugin to do native c/c++ compilation. Java is possible, but not an option for me.

Comment: It is easy to add a task to build the Linux lib with host toolchain to build.gradle, but the advantages of such unification are unclear.

Comment: Ok, could you please post some hints or examples. And are there differences in adding tasks for libs vs executables?

Comment: Naturally, cmake script for executable is different from library. Also, I don't think cmake for Android can build executables.